# LINQ deferred execution with a function's result as source (e.g. Console.ReadLine)

Tags: c#, linq, deferred-execution

A function's result is the source for a *LINQ query*. I want it to be evaluated lazily, every time I use the query, not be locked when I create it. This is an example of what I mean:

```
var query = from c in Console.ReadLine()
            group c by char.IsDigit(c) into gr
            select new { IsDigit = gr.Key, Count = gr.Count() };
```

`Console.WriteLine()` runs only once - when `query` is created, even without calling a terminating method on it like `ToList()`. What I would want is for `Console.WriteLine()` (or any other function in its place) to be executed only when I use the query with `ToList()` or `Count()` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind a bit of extra infrastructure, it's not too bad - you can create a `DeferredEnumerable<T>` class that just executes the given delegate every time it's asked for an iterator. A static non-generic class can then help with type inference. Complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

// Just for type inference...
public static class DeferredEnumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> For<T>(Func<IEnumerable<T>> func) =>
        new DeferredEnumerable<T>(func);
}

public sealed class DeferredEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly Func<IEnumerable<T>> func;

    public DeferredEnumerable(Func<IEnumerable<T>> func)
    {
        this.func = func;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => func().GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var query = 
            from c in DeferredEnumerable.For(Console.ReadLine)
            group c by char.IsDigit(c) into gr
            select new { IsDigit = gr.Key, Count = gr.Count() };


        Console.WriteLine("First go round");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, query));

        Console.WriteLine("Second go round");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, query));
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking the same, but with just static generic iterator method.

Comment: @Ivan: As a type it's easier to reuse.

Comment: Sure. As soon as its encapsulated in a public static method, the implementation does not really matter (could be one or another). Good candidate for MoreLinq? :)

Comment: @IvanStoev: True, the static class *could* be the only exposed API... not sure. As for MoreLINQ, feel free to file a github issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 solutions, but they are really ugly and I wouldn't want to use them

---

**Solution 1**

This one is especially ugly as you need an additional function (it can't be anonymous)

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetDeferredConsoleReadLine()
{
    yield return Console.ReadLine();
}

var query = from line in GetDeferredConsoleReadLine()
            from c in line
            group c by char.IsDigit(c) into gr
            select new { IsDigit = gr.Key, Count = gr.Count() };
```

This uses the deferred execution of an enumerable function `yield return`ing the function's result.

---

**Solution 2**

This uses another unwieldy construct of a LINQ query inside another one, which returns one element (the thing is that it needs a source - I use a one-element string and discard the result but that isn't really clean)

```
var query = from line in
                from _ in "1"
                select Console.ReadLine()
            from c in line
            group c by char.IsDigit(c) into gr
            select new { IsDigit = gr.Key, Count = gr.Count() };
```

---

Is there any other way I could do that, possibly without having `SelectMany` in the query?

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the query in a separate method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        foreach (var y in RunQuery()) {
            Console.WriteLine($"{y.IsDigit}: {y.Count}");
        }
    }
}

class A{public bool IsDigit { get; set; } public int Count { get; set; } }

private static IEnumerable<A> RunQuery()
{
    return from c in Console.ReadLine()
                group c by char.IsDigit(c) into gr
                select new A { IsDigit = gr.Key, Count = gr.Count() };
}
```

Comment: That's not really scalable as you'd have to create a new function and a class  for every query you want to use in the code